# javascript: 2 toggles not working on the same page because of same classname

Tags: javascript, sitecore

I am new to JS and i am in an issue, I have added 2 identical sitecore modules on same page which has 2 identical script which toggles the class name.

```
var accItem = document.getElementsByClassName('accordionItem');
var accHD = document.getElementsByClassName('accordionItemHeading');
for (i = 0; i < accHD.length; i++) {
    accHD[i].addEventListener('click', toggleItem, false);
}
function toggleItem() {
    var itemClass = this.parentNode.className;
    for (i = 0; i < accItem.length; i++) {
        accItem[i].className = 'accordionItem close';
    }
    if (itemClass == 'accordionItem close') {
        this.parentNode.className = 'accordionItem open';
    }
}
```

The problem is that only one module click is working because of the identical className. Now how can i use "this" to solve my problem and both modules should work despite of having same classname?

Edit: HTML Code:

```
<div class="accordionContent">
 <div class="accordionItem close" style="display: block;">
   <div class="accordionItemHeading">
   CONTENT
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="accordionContent">
 <div class="accordionItem close" style="display: block;">
  <div class="accordionItemHeading">
   CONTENT
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't use the same class name

Comment: Depends on your html structure.  I think you should generate a list of "items in THIS accordion" within the toggleItem function.  But that depends on being able to traverse the DOM to a parent element which can be identified as an accordion container.

Comment: You could use GetElementById and give them two IDs.

Comment: @James
Actually, i cant change the classname or use GetElementById due to other restrictions, i need to find a way out.
Also i have added my html code please check that once.

Comment: I didn't suggest you do either of those.

Comment: You never declare `i`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to get your HTML working but the approach I would try in the toggleItem function is as follows:

```
var accHD = document.getElementsByClassName('accordionItemHeading');

for (i = 0; i < accHD.length; i++) {
    accHD[i].addEventListener('click', toggleItem, false);
}

function toggleItem() {
  // get the parent accordion element
  let parentAccordion = this.closest(".accordionContent");
  // get all the accordion items within the parent
  let itemsInParent = parentAccordion.querySelectorAll(".accordionItem");
  // make them all closed
  itemsInParent.forEach(item => item.className = 'accordionItem close');
  // make this one open
  this.parentNode.className = 'accordionItem open';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works nearly fine for me just one thing, I am able to open the items but can't close them up again after clicking the same open item. How can that be achieved?

Comment: Should work.  Maybe I got your html structure wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So in your script you're referring to accordion-headings but it wasn't included in your HTML. I assume you want to use those headings to be the ones that activate the toggle mechanism. Because your HTML code wasn't complete I've created a possible example based on what I thought it would need for your code to work.

There really isn't much difference, most of the code you've written was all right. I've just added the `event` parameter to the function toggle. That one makes it possible to retrace the target that fired the click event (the accordionHeading) and from there we can for example get the parent (the accordion-container) and then from there we can go back to find the actual element accordionItem inside this container.

```js
let accordionHeadings = document.getElementsByClassName('accordionHeading');

for(let i=0; i<accordionHeadings.length; i++){
   accordionHeadings[i].addEventListener('click', toggle);
}

function toggle(event){
  let accordionItem = event.target.parentElement.lastElementChild;
  if(accordionItem.classList.contains('close')){
    accordionItem.classList.remove('close');
    accordionItem.classList.add('open');
  }else{
    accordionItem.classList.remove('open');
    accordionItem.classList.add('close');
  }
}
```

```css
.accordionContent{ padding: 2em; margin: 0.5em; background-color: lightgrey; }
.open{ display: block; }
.close{ display: none; }
```

```html
<div class="accordionContent">
  <div class="accordionHeading">
    Click me to toggle the content
  </div>
  <div class="accordionItem close">
    CONTENT
   </div>
</div>

<div class="accordionContent">
  <div class="accordionHeading">
    Click me to toggle the content
  </div>
  <div class="accordionItem close">
    CONTENT
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your response on this. I have updated the structure of the HTML code. The heading was under the accordionItem. Sorry for this late edit.
We need to toggle the accordionItem with close and open and the heading is the clickable part so we need to catch it in event. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Hey, i corrected the js accordingly but the error your JS is giving is regarding the "accordionHeadings " , it is been declared once so cant be used again as it has "let". If you change the "let" to "var" the situation is again same, only the second module works not the first.

Comment: This script works for both the toggles, you only need to copy/use this code once in your project. So no need to delcare accordionHeadings twice and you could use let without a problem as long as it's declarded outside the scope of the functions (as it is in the example). You can click on the `run code snippet` button in my answer and see that with this code both lines are able to toggle